# Insertar datos recibidos de una base de datos en un campo texfield

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos

Alguien podria decirme como muestro datos (recibidos de una base de datos) en varios  textfield?

Aqui el codigo  de buscar :)

```
public void buscar(String id_usu) {
    try {
        Object row[] = new Object[15];
        conectar conexion = new conectar();
        Connection con = conexion.getconectar();
        String sentencia = "SELECT * FROM evaluacion_antropometrica WHERE id_usu="+id_usu+" ";
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sentencia);

        while (rs.next()) {
               
            for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
                row[i] = rs.getObject(i + 1);
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Estatura usuario: "+row[1]+"\nPeso usuario:"+row[2]+"\nmedida brazo izquierdo:"+row[3]+"\nmedida brazo derecho:"+row[4]+"\nmedida pecho:"+row[5]+"\nmedida pierna izquierda:"+row[6]+"\nmedida pierna derecha:"+row[7]+"\nmedida cintura:"+row[8]+"\npantorrilla izquierda:"+row[9]+"\npantorrilla derecha:"+row[10]+"\nimcresultado:"+row[11]+"\ncuello:"+row[12]+"\nimc verificar:"+row[13]+"\nIdentificacion:"+row[14]);
        conexion.desconectar();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
} // cierra buscar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
txtCampoEstatura.setText(row[1].toString());
txtPesoUsuario.setText(row[2].toString());
```

... y así con todos los campos.

Comment: Mira que cuando pongo los txt no me los llama ...

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar un SqlDataReader, te dejo este ejemplo para que puedas adaptarlo a tu codigo, saludos

```html
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("connection string")) {
cn.Open();

string query = "SELECT * FROM NombreTabla WHERE Id = @id";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text));

SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read()) {
TextBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(reader("nombrecampo1"));
TextBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(reader("nombrecampo2"));
TextBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(reader("nombrecampo3"));
}

}
```

Podrias intentar algo asi

```html
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Estatura usuario: "+Convert.ToString(reader("nombrecampo1"))+"\nPeso usuario:"+Convert.ToString(reader("nombrecampo2"))...;
```